# How do I hide the Admin Menu item in Wordpress Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to hide the Wordpress admin menu sub menu item.

I have tried various snippets found here on StackOverflow and on Wordpress in `functions.php`, but nothing is working.

This is the url to the page I want to hide: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=be-websites`

Comment: Who do you want to hide it from? Everyone or just non-admins?

Comment: I want to be able to hide it from everyone

Answer (score 1):

The reason the other code snippet which included `remove_menu_page()` did not work was that it targets top level admin menu items whereas `remove_submenu_page` will remove the submenu pages just as the function name suggests.

the first parameter the function takes is the slug for the parent menu and the second is the slug for the sub menu you want to remove. [Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page)

Note: This function simply removes the menu it does not replace filtering users' permissions

```
function remove_admin_menu_items(){
    remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'be-websites' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_items', 999);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but it didn't work. I put it at the bottom of the theme-functions.php file, saved, refreshed, but the submenu is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the link Dan, but I found that conversation a little confusing and I don't have the privileges to add a comment. That is related to plugins and mine is related to a menu created by the theme

Comment: I edited my answer. See that and if that doesn't work I apologize but I am out of solutions